# How to filter using fetch to get accurate results?

Tags: filter, dynamics-crm, fetch, dynamics-crm-2016, fetchxml

I need to get all accounts that have phonecalls in `state` <kbd>not</kbd> `open`, so I created a query on fetch and got some results.

After checking my results I found that I got all accounts that have minimum 1 phonecall that was not open, but I need to get the accounts that **all** of their connected phonecalls are not open (can't have even 1 in open state) is it possible to do by fetch ?

** by NOT OPEN I mean state of Canceled or Completed.

Here is my fetch query:

```
@"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='name' />                                        
    <order attribute='accountamount' descending='true' />
    <link-entity name='phonecall' from='regardingobjectid' to='accountid' alias='ab'>
      <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='statecode' operator='ne' value='0' />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>";
```

Comment: Pls show your attempted query..

Comment: @ArunVinoth I added it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is Unmatch query. This can be achieved in 2 queries using fetchxml.

**First Query**: You have to pull all the Accounts with open phonecalls.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
  <entity name="account" >
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="accountamount" descending="true" />
    <link-entity name="phonecall" from="regardingobjectid" to="accountid" alias="ab" >
      <filter type="and" >
        <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

**Second Query**: Iterate & pass the first query Account resultset as `<value>` like below, to filter out them.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
  <entity name="account" >
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="primarycontactid" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="accountid" operator="not-in" >
        <value><GUID of ACCOUNT1 with OPEN PHONECALL></value>
        <value><GUID of ACCOUNT2 with OPEN PHONECALL></value>
        <value><GUID of ACCOUNT3 with OPEN PHONECALL></value>
      </condition>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

[Read for idea](https://dynamicscrmpros.com/dynamics-crm-2011-build-unmatch-query-ssrs-report-using-fetchxml/)

Comment: Arun , do you mean to get 2 Entitycollections : 1-all accounts 2-all accounts that has an open phonecalls and to cut out all the accounts with open phonecalls from all accounts?